# Overlaying watermark on \includepdf *at varying defined locations on successive pages*

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdfpages, watermark

When using [advice elsewhere here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12838/can-i-add-tikzpictures-to-pages-included-with-pdfpages) to place a watermark over every page of an `\includepdf`, I'd like to vary the location of the watermarks on each page.  One very laborious solution is to include the PDF one page at a time (see "This works" segment).  I hoped to use [this neat list-as-queue idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230618/iterator-like-command-where-each-use-expands-to-an-item-from-list-defined-earli) to queue up all of the co-ordinates, then pop them from within the `pdfpages` `pagecommand` on each page (see "This doesn't" segment; needs commenting-out for "This works" to complete).

Unfortunately my understanding of the underlying mechanisms fails me at this point: the error `Missing \endcsname inserted` is completely opaque to me.  I'm guessing that the `\el{}` macro to pop co-ordinates can't be used in the context I'm using it in; would be grateful for suggestions for a fix..

Two support documents required; I'd suggest grabbing this for the PNG watermark image, `alpha_noset.png`:

```
wget https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/alpha_noset.png
```

.. and copying in any two-or-more-page PDF you have handy as `inclusion.pdf`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{letter}

\usepackage{tikz}      % Watermark overlay
\usepackage{pdfpages}  % Multi-page PDF inclusions
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Graphical inclusions
\usepackage{xparse}

% Pull values out of a queue, from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230618/iterator-like-command-where-each-use-expands-to-an-item-from-list-defined-earli
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\deflist}{O{,}m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_narebski_list_seq { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\el}{}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \l_narebski_list_seq { 1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_narebski_list_seq \l_narebski_waste_tl
 }
\seq_new:N \l_narebski_list_seq
\tl_new:N \l_narebski_waste_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\signature{x}
\address{Etc.}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{To whom it may concern,}

\opening{Dear sir/madam,}
Really.
\closing{Yours sincerely,}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This works: include PDF one page at a time, repositioning the
% watermark individually for each page.

% Integration of tikzpicture to every \includepdf taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12838/can-i-add-tikzpictures-to-pages-included-with-pdfpages

\setkeys{pdfpages}{pagecommand={
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt] at (\atx,\aty) {%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm,angle=\ata]{alpha_noset.png}%
  };%
\end{tikzpicture}
}}

% Co-ordinates are x=\atx, y=\aty and rotation angle=\ata.
\newcommand{\atx}{11} \newcommand{\aty}{3} \newcommand{\ata}{15}
\includepdf[pages={1}]{inclusion.pdf}
\renewcommand{\atx}{-2} \renewcommand{\aty}{-18} \renewcommand{\ata}{90}
\includepdf[pages={2}]{inclusion.pdf}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This doesn't, but I'd prefer it: queue up list of watermark co-
% ordinates and pop 'em off as needed.

% Here we line up the list of co-ordinates; in normal text, \el{}
% would retrieve them, one at a time (I could say "first: \el{},
% second: \el{}, third: \el{}", etc.).  Within the pdfpages pagecommand,
% \el{} causes an error instead.
\deflist{11,3,15,-2,-18,90} % Same sequence of atx,aty,ata values as above.

\setkeys{pdfpages}{pagecommand={
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt] at (\el{},\el{}) {%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm,angle=\el{}]{alpha_noset.png}%
  };%
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
%% COMMENT/UNCOMMENT THE NEXT LINE TO SUPPRESS/GENERATE THE FAIL:
\includepdf[pages={1,2}]{inclusion.pdf}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: TikZ supports random numbers; Why don't you pass random numbers to your \atx, \aty? See tutorial 4 in the pgf manual at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf or code like `\foreach \atx, \aty in {1/1,...,10/10} {\pgfmathparse{rnd}\pgfmathresult}` (there is better code code than this, look through the manual.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response; that loop structure looks really useful, but since I need the values in what I'd (in other programming languages) term a callback (pdfpages' pagecommand), retrieving the next three co-ordinates on each call, I can't go through them with a foreach: instead I think need something with ["yield"-like behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)).

I did experiment with random numbers, but in this instance I want to choose specific co-ordinates.

Comment: This won't work. `\seq_pop...` is not expandable. You need to get the values before executing the \node command.

Comment: If I try to get the values in the pagecommand but before the \node it still doesn't seem to work though; is there any approach that you think would make this general idea work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the non-expandable command `\seq_pop_left:NN` in this context.
Instead you can use `\seq_pop_left:NN` first to extract the object into a new macro, then use this new macro in the `\node` command.

This would not give the expected result through, because you defined `\l_narebski_list_seq` to be local. So LaTeX will always use the first values, because the "pop" is no longer visible after the current group. You can use a global sequence instead:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{letter}

\usepackage{tikz}      % Watermark overlay
\usepackage{pdfpages}  % Multi-page PDF inclusions
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Graphical inclusions
\usepackage{xparse}

% Pull values out of a queue, from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230618/iterator-like-command-where-each-use-expands-to-an-item-from-list-defined-earli
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\deflist}{O{,}m}
 {
   \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_narebski_list_seq { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\el}{m}
 {
  \seq_gpop_left:NN \g_narebski_list_seq #1
 }
\seq_new:N \g_narebski_list_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\signature{x}
\address{Etc.}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{To whom it may concern,}

\opening{Dear sir/madam,}
Really.
\closing{Yours sincerely,}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\deflist{11,3,15,-2,-18,90} % Same sequence of atx,aty,ata values as above.

\setkeys{pdfpages}{pagecommand={
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \el\atx \el\aty \el\ata
  \node[inner sep=0pt] at (\atx,\aty) {%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm,angle=\ata]{alpha_noset.png}%
  };%
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\includepdf[pages={1,2}]{tittoc.pdf}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Superb!  This works perfectly; thank you very much Marcel :)