# Include a PDF-file and write text above on the same page

Tags: formatting, pdfpages

I would like to have a section where I insert a PDF-page and write a few lines of text before. What I got:

```
\section{FOO}
%some text is following
\includepdf[scale=0.9,pages=1,pagecommand={},offset=0 -3cm]{myPDF.pdf}
```

Sadly the `\includepdf`-command seems to produce a pagebreak right when it is used. One workaround is to insert the `\section{FOO}` into the `pagecommand`-option of `\includepdf`, but in that case I am not able to write some text between the PDF and the section-heading. How can I have heading, text and PDF on the same page?

Comment: We have no the pdf (or one similar with yours), no MWE to work on... So, Just an idea is to use tikz with overlay to add text on a layer over the included pdf... By searching "stackexchange tikz overlay includepdf" I found this:" https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433369/120578 . Possible dulicate if you manage to use it

Comment: @koleygr Thanks for your answer. That was not exactly what I wanted. What did the trick was simply replacing then `\includepdf` by `\includegraphics` since the `includepdf` uses the `includegraphics` internally and `includegraphics` seems not to be inserting a pagebreak

Comment: Note the undocumented [page=...] option for \includegraphics.